# Uploading Image to tumblr using OAuthConsumer for iOS

Tags: ios, http, oauth, tumblr

I'm using the [OAuthConsumer](http://code.google.com/p/oauthconsumer/) in my iOS application which makes use of the [Tumblr API](http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api/v2#posting). Making API-Calls in general works fine. However, I struggle to upload any media. When all the parameters of my requests are ints or strings, I add them just like that:

```
    [request setParameters:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                        [OARequestParameter requestParameterWithName:@"x_auth_username" value:username],
                        [OARequestParameter requestParameterWithName:@"x_auth_password" value:password],
                        nil]];
```

That obviously won't work for e.g. images.
I figured out that I probably will have to send this data as `multipart/form-data` instead of `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and therefore, it won't have any effect on the oAuth signature. However, as far as I can tell, the OAuthConsumer only supports `x-www-form-urlencoded` (with the relevant code lying in the `NSMutableURLRequest+Parameters.m`). However, I'm not sure whether this is correct and, if so, I don't really know  how to modify the `Consumer` correctly. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out my self. There are several parts to this and since I saw other people having similar questions, I'll go into full length:

First of all, I was using an outdated version of OAuthConsumer. Instead of using the version that is [linked on Google Code](http://code.google.com/p/oauthconsumer/), you should use the more recent version [from github](https://github.com/jdg/oauthconsumer) since it includes the means to send a multipart form with more than strings in it.

Now, if I'm not completely wrong, what you should theoretically do now is the following:

```
//Setup the request...
[request setParameters:params];    
[request attachFileWithName:@"data" filename:@"photo.jpg" contentType:@"image/jpeg" data:dataProp.data];
//Setup the fetcher and send the request...
```

This will generate an oAuth signature which includes only the `oauth_...`-variables, putting all your other variables into the multipart form. This is how it should be and according to the documentation, you should be fine. Unfortunately, you aren't, tumblr will return a 401 error, resulting most likely from an invalid signature.

Here is what you really have to do:

```
//Setup the request...
[request setParameters:params];
[request prepare]; //Whaaaat?
[request attachFileWithName:@"data" filename:@"photo.jpg" contentType:@"image/jpeg" data:dataProp.data];
//Setup the fetcher, make sure "prepare" isn't called again, send the request...
```

This will work... Again, I'm pretty sure that this is not how oAuth is supposed to handle this but at least it works.

Comment: The key to this for me was "make sure "prepare" isn't called again".

Comment: Great! This worked for me using Mac OS X to access the Etsy API.

Answer (score 1):

Tumblr's implementation of OAuth is pretty strange I'd say. I found why it is OK for authentication and blog request ([see here](http://github.com/nquinlan/Tumblr-OAuth/issues/2)). As I know, Tumblr works better with new OAuth library ([this one](https://github.com/jdg/oauthconsumer)). I my self uselessly spent some time trying to make all work on old OAuth for compatibility with ShareKit.
The solution I found suggest using [ASIFormDataRequest](https://github.com/pokeb/asi-http-request) and signing it with OAuth authentication information ([originally found here](http://hytgbn.net/2012/02/tip-of-uploading-images-to-tumblr-using-oauth-on-ios/)). Yes, it looks like trying to crossbreed a hedgehog with a grass snake, but somehow it works for single images. But, after modifying this code, I couldn't upload multiple images.
Another solution is ["TumblrUploadr"](http://github.com/vvanhee/TumblrUploadr), but it looks a bit too raw.