# How to Post image or Text in Tumblr iPhone

Tags: ios

I am Working on Tumblr integration in iPhone but not able to login

Downloded the SDK from following Url:-
     https://github.com/tumblr/TMTumblrSDK

Now i want to Upload the pic on tumblr

Comment: Work on it, narrow down your problem and then ask question if you have any. At this point it's too broad (can be covered in a tutorial) for a question.

Comment: i m search on google bt not give any detail thats why i upload the question bro

Comment: I did a quick search my self, here is a helpful link that i found http://stackoverflow.com/a/10217264/656600

Comment: i m already check that tell me in this post using the OAthConsumer but i want use the TMTumblr SDK ? Both are the same thing or not

Comment: http://hytgbn.net/2012/02/tip-of-uploading-images-to-tumblr-using-oauth-on-ios/ plz see this for this post very help full

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have downloaded Tumbler SDK, then, Insice example folder you'll see sample project named "PhotoPostExample".

This contains following code. Which is responsible for image uploading.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    [button setTitle:@"Post photo" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button sizeToFit];
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(postPhoto) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.view addSubview:button];

    // TODO: Fill in your keys and secrets

    [TMAPIClient sharedInstance].OAuthConsumerKey = @"";
    [TMAPIClient sharedInstance].OAuthConsumerSecret = @"";
    [TMAPIClient sharedInstance].OAuthToken = @"";
    [TMAPIClient sharedInstance].OAuthTokenSecret = @"";
}

- (void)postPhoto {
    // TODO: Fill in your blog name

    [[TMAPIClient sharedInstance] photo:@""
                          filePathArray:@[[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"blue" ofType:@"png"]]
                       contentTypeArray:@[@"image/png"]
                          fileNameArray:@[@"blue.png"]
                             parameters:@{@"caption" : @"Caption"}
                               callback:^(id response, NSError *error) {
                                   if (error)
                                       NSLog(@"Error posting to Tumblr");
                                   else
                                       NSLog(@"Posted to Tumblr");
                               }];
}
```

Hope this will help, others.

Comment: when we include the Thumblr SDK give the error that TMAPIClient is not define

Comment: @AhmadDurrani You'll need to read the documentation: Specially https://github.com/tumblr/TMTumblrSDK#getting-started

Comment: i m include this sdk bt still give the same problem bro

Comment: and also read their documentation

Comment: but its only for Platform 5 Now plz tell me what i can do ?

Comment: @AhmadDurrani Let me check, I can come with a solution latest by to evening. As I am involve in some of my work right now. And this seems like time taking task.

Comment: hmm k when u can do it plz send me in my email i m really tnx a lot my email is ahmadyarimran@yahoo.com